# Why is 'break' not inserted to every sequence

Tags: python

I need add 'break' into every sequence, which starts with an alphabet and ends with a number.

Here is my code

```
tune = input().rstrip()
tune = list(tune)
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
numbers = "1234567890"
s =''
for i in range(len(tune)):
  
  if tune[i] in letters:
    if tune[i-1] in numbers:
      tune.insert(i, 'break')
tune.pop(0)
print(*tune)
for k in tune:
  s += k
s = s.replace('+',' tighten ')
s = s.replace('-',' loosen ')
s = s.replace('break','\n')

print(s)
```

Here is the input and output

Input:

```
T+1S-1R+2Q-2P+3O-3N+4M-4L+5K-5J+6I-6H+7G-7F+8E-8D+9C-9
```

My output:

```
T tighten 1
S loosen 1
R tighten 2
Q loosen 2
P tighten 3
O loosen 3
N tighten 4
M loosen 4
L tighten 5
K loosen 5
J tighten 6
I loosen 6
H tighten 7
G loosen 7F tighten 8E loosen 8D tighten 9C loosen 9
```

(idk why the code suddenly stop adding the breaks, so the list just joins up with each other at the end)

Expected output:

```
T tighten 1
S loosen 1
R tighten 2
Q loosen 2
P tighten 3
O loosen 3
N tighten 4
M loosen 4
L tighten 5
K loosen 5
J tighten 6
I loosen 6
H tighten 7
G loosen 7
F tighten 8
E loosen 8
D tighten 9
C loosen 9
```

Comment: Note on the first iteration of your loop... `tune[i-1]` is going to equal the last character of `tune`... and mutating a list while iterating over it is going to lead to headaches

Comment: Are you allowed to do something like: `re.sub(r'([A-Z])([+-])(\d)', lambda m: m.expand(r'\1 {} \3\n').format({'+': 'tighten', '-': 'loosen'}[m.group(2)]), s)` ?

Comment: the reason is that you're increasing the size of the list while iterating, by the time you arrive and the end of your range over the original size of your list, lets called N, your list if of size N+M where M is the number of "break" you inserted along the way.

Comment: @jon I would add + on the letters and digits

Comment: Is it possible the numbers will ever be more than one digit?

Answer (score 1):

Size of list is increasing dynamically as you are appending 'break' again and again but for loop will only work till initially entered range. Using a while loop can solve this problem.

```
tune = input().rstrip()
tune = list(tune)
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
numbers = "1234567890"
s =''
i=0
while i<len(tune):
  if tune[i] in letters:
    if tune[i-1] in numbers:
      tune.insert(i, 'break')
  i+=1
tune.pop(0)
print(*tune)
for k in tune:
  s += k
s = s.replace('+',' tighten ')
s = s.replace('-',' loosen ')
s = s.replace('break','\n')

print(s)
```

Though there can be more optimised way to solve this problem. This simple tweaking can provide the desired output as well.

Hope this helps✌️

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want to take your input and split it in chunks, the are many ways to do it, one is for example using slice notation over your string

```
>>> text = "T+1S-1R+2Q-2P+3O-3N+4M-4L+5K-5J+6I-6H+7G-7F+8E-8D+9C-9"
>>> tunes = [text[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(text),3)]
>>> tunes
['T+1', 'S-1', 'R+2', 'Q-2', 'P+3', 'O-3', 'N+4', 'M-4', 'L+5', 'K-5', 'J+6', 'I-6', 'H+7', 'G-7', 'F+8', 'E-8', 'D+9', 'C-9']
```

and them process those chunks

Comment: This should be the preferred answer since it's very pythonic (also the question clearly suffers from the XY problem).

If one needs to arrive to the desired end result from what the author posted one can simply add `map(lambda chunk : "tighten" if chunk[1] == "+" else "loosen", tunes)` to parse the + and - into strings.

Answer (score 0):

If your end result is a printout of the contents as shown, then I would do it this way:

```
tune = input().rstrip()
for i in range(2, len(tune), 3):
    s = z[i-2: i+1]
    c = 'tighten'
    if s[1] == '-':
        c = 'loosen'
    print(f'{s[0]} {c} {s[2]}')
```